# Multiple value to UIPicker View

Tags: iphone

I have a UI picker view to store child details, i got the value through a web service.I was added child name to picker view , now it shows all childs.

I also have one more value child id to store in the picker view, when a user select a child i need to get the id of the corresponding child.How i add multiple values to same row a pickerview.

Thanks,
Companion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it you want to store its Id too then you have to use an object to handle this

```
int selectedRow = [childPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
Child *childObj = [childsList objectAtIndex:selectedRow];
```

Here in childObject, You have stored this values.
childObj.childName;
childObj.childId;

Answer (score 0):

You can basically use a pickerView with two components.set the text to picker label based on component